# html2canvas and pdfmake create blank pdf

Tags: angularjs, html2canvas, pdfmake

I'm trying to generate a pdf from an html div with html2canvas and pdfMake but always got a blank page or just part of the div! How can I get the entire div content?

Here is the js code :

```
$scope.PrintFiche = function () {
    var prom = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        html2canvas(document.getElementById('DevisImpression'), {
            onrendered: function (canvas) {
                var data = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
                var docDefinition = {
                    content: [{
                        image: data
                    }]
                };
                resolve(docDefinition);
            }
        });
    })

    prom.then(function (docDef) {

        pdfMake.createPdf(docDef).download($scope.FicheName + ".pdf");
    })

}
```

And the html :

```
<div class="Partie" id="DevisImpression">
        <div id="PartieInner">
            <h2 id="TitreDevis">
                <b>
                    Etablissement du devis
                </b>
            </h2>
            <div id="ImgVoitureDevis">
                <img id="ImgVoitureAdapt" src="../../Assets/Images/test.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div id="OptMult">
                <table id="TableDevis">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="td1">
                            Modèle :
                        </td>
                        <td class="td2">
                            {{modele.displayName}}
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="td1">
                            Classe :
                        </td>
                        <td class="td2">
                            {{classe.displayName}}
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="td1">
                            Moteur :
                        </td>
                        <td class="td2">
                            {{moteur.displayName}}
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="td1">
                            Couleur :
                        </td>
                        <td class="td2">
                            {{couleur.displayName}}
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="td1">
                            Jantes :
                        </td>
                        <td class="td2">
                            {{jante.displayName}}
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
            <table id="Devis">
                <tr>
                    <th class="tdDevis2">
                        Options
                    </th>
                    <th class="tdDevis2">
                        Prix
                    </th>
                </tr>
                <tr ng-repeat="optionDev in optionsDevis">
                    <td class="td3">
                        {{optionDev.displayName}}
                    </td>
                    <td class="td4">
                        {{optionDev.prix}} €
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <h2 id="TotalTitre">
            <b>
                TOTAL
            </b>
        </h2>
        <input type="text" id="Total" value="{{total}} €" disabled />
        <br />
    </div>
```

Comment: are you getting any kind of errors?

Comment: No nothing! Just a blank pdf. I'm working with a friend and he can get the pdf we're looking for when I can't.

Comment: found similar issue on another thread..  see if this helps   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34893050/empty-pdf-report-is-generated-when-we-have-multiple-graphs-using-html2canvas-and

Comment: @davidlima-duret did you get any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I have a simple solution. Try this.

```
$scope.downloadQuotation = function () {
        html2canvas(document.getElementById('rosterPrintView'), {
            onrendered: function (canvas) {
                var data = canvas.toDataURL();
                var docDefinition = {
                    content: [{
                        image: data,
                        width: 500
                    }]
                };
                pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).download("Roster.pdf");
            }
        });
    };
```

Comment: Hmm.. What does this do?

Comment: Hey, I'm trying to use your solution but it didn't work.

Comment: html2canvas(document.getElementById("PDFprint"), {
      onrendered: function (canvas) {
        var data = canvas.toDataURL();
        var docDefinition = {
          content: [{
            image: data,
            width: 1200
          }]
        };
        pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).download("test.pdf");
      }
    });

This is my code, but i don't know why the pdfMake code isn't running.

Comment: @ZurielRodriguez Any updates on  this? I am trying the same thing in a banana dashboard to generate a PDF. But am getting the error "Error: html2canvas is not defined this.to_pdf@http://localhost:8983/solr/banana/app/services/dashboard.js:269:13"