# Getting image on page 1 of 2 page pdf

Tags: javascript, angular, pdf, jspdf, html2canvas

I am creating an image with html2canvas and with jsPDF with Angular4. I want to place this image on page 1 of a 2 page generated pdf.

But it seems that the line,

```
 doc.save('test.pdf');
```

needs to be inside the function just after `htm2canvas()`. Because if I place it outside this it will not include the image in the pdf.

```
generatePDF(){
      var doc = new jsPDF();
      doc.text(50,90,this.problems.length.toString());
      doc.text(50,100,'page 1')
      doc.addPage();
      doc.text(50,100,'page 2')
      html2canvas(document.getElementById('graph')).then(function(canvas) {
        var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
        doc.addImage(img, 'JPEG', 100, 100);
        doc.save('test.pdf');
    });
    // doc.save('test.pdf');//fails to add image to pdf
  }
```

I can't place the `addPage()` after the `html2canvas()`, because when `html2canvas` is called that generates the pdf and nothing after it will be included.

Seems the only way is to put the `jsPDF` inside the `html2canvas()` like this,

```
  generatePDF(){
    html2canvas(document.getElementById('graph')).then(function(canvas) {
      var doc = new jsPDF();
      doc.text(50,100,'page 1')
      var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
      doc.addImage(img, 'JPEG', 100, 100);
      doc.addPage();
      doc.text(50,100,'page 2')
      doc.save('test.pdf');
    });
```

This does work.

But then the problem is that I can't use a variable from outside, when inside `html2canvas()`, like this.

```
  generatePDF(){
    console.log("outside: this.problem.length = " + this.problems.length);// works

    html2canvas(document.getElementById('graph')).then(function(canvas) {
      console.log("inside: this.problem.length = " + this.problems.length);// not working!!!

      var doc = new jsPDF();
      doc.text(50,100,'page 1');
      var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
      doc.addImage(img, 'JPEG', 100, 100);
      doc.addPage();
      doc.text(50,100,'page 2')
      doc.save('test.pdf');
    });
    // doc.save('test.pdf');//fails to add image to pdf
  }
```

package.json has the types for html2canvas and jspdf:

```
...
"@types/html2canvas": "^0.5.35",
"@types/jspdf": "^1.1.31",
"@types/lodash": "^4.14.74",
"html2canvas": "^0.5.0-beta4",
"jspdf": "^1.3.5",
...
```

The full code is [here](https://github.com/shanegibney/angular-basic-maths-app/tree/master/src/app) on github, with the relevant code commented out at the bottom of `app.component.ts` on line 428.

Possible solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34893050/empty-pdf-report-is-generated-when-we-have-multiple-graphs-using-html2canvas-and?rq=1).

Comment: May be a silly question, but did you install `@types/html2canvas` and `@types/jspdf`? These should give you the scope you need to access `this.problem` in a typescript environment if you haven't.

Comment: Not a stupid question, but yes I installed both and with @types/... as you suggest, thanks for looking at it anyway.

Comment: Possible solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34893050/empty-pdf-report-is-generated-when-we-have-multiple-graphs-using-html2canvas-and?rq=1 will try in tomorrow

Comment: Sounds exactly like the problem/solution!

Comment: Yes, pity I know little about promises.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you can access that variable. The problem is that each `function` creates its own scope and defines `this` as a link to its own context, so the html2canvas then-callback's `this` is not the same as generatePDF function's `this`. This is a part of basic paradigm of javascript as a functional language.

The simplest solution is to save the context in a local variable:

```
generatePDF() {
  var self = this;
  console.log("outside: self.problem.length = " + self.problems.length);

  html2canvas(document.getElementById('graph')).then(function(canvas) {
    console.log("inside: self.problem.length = " + self.problems.length);
    // ...
  });
  // ...
}
```

Another option is to use ES arrow function (in case of ES6 is appropriate for your project; and I guess it's so due to Angular 4) because the arrow function saves the parent context:

```
generatePDF(){
  console.log("outside: this.problem.length = " + this.problems.length);

  html2canvas(document.getElementById('graph')).then((canvas) => {
    console.log("inside: this.problem.length = " + this.problems.length);
    // ...
  });
  // ...
}
```

Not sure if it's all the story, but hope this helps!

Comment: Brilliant thank you so much. I've fundamentals of JS still to learn, but delighted to have this sorted. Thanks Denis

Answer (score 1):

This function is asynchronous:

```
html2canvas(document.getElementById('graph'))
```

You can have access to the generated image only inside the callback function. If are going to use html2canvas to generate images, then all your pdf-related code must be inside the callback. It's really what you already did. If you're going to need another images in pdf, you'll have more nested callbacks and this line `doc.save('test.pdf');` must be inside the last one.

Comment: Yes, but what about 'this.problems', how can I access it to include it in the pdf? Thanks

Comment: @ShaneG, about this: 'this' inside the function is different from the outside 'this'. So you should store the top-level 'this' in a variable and then use it inside the function.